# Не подтягиваются данные из базы

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть такая проблема, которая за последние несколько дней вынесла мозг и мне и коллеге-фронтендеру. Имеется сайт. Залит на digital ocean. База данных находится на m lab-e. Проблема в том, что при обращении к серверу некоторые запросы выполняются нормально, к примеру отображение/добавление/удаление категорий, а также добавление и удаление книг, а вот отображение книг не работает. Данный баг присутствует только на проде, локальные версии того-же кода, ссылающиея на ту-же базу данных в mlab-e работают нормально и данные подтягиваются. Мы пока грешим на кеширование на стороне сервера (nginx-a) но уверенности нет. Я, как ни старался, не смог найти файл кэша чтобы его удалить - в nginx.conf он не прописан. Может кто-то сможет подсказать чем может быть вызвано такое поведение или хотя бы как можно проверить кэшируются ли данные.

Могу добавить, что раньше запросы выполнялись правильно. Проблемы начались после последнего апдейта, касающегося как раз логики выборки книг, но повторюсь - локально все работает...

Answer (score 0):

В заголовках нужно кэш отключать. Можно открыть девтулз и посмотреть откуда запрос идёт, из кэша или сервера. Может с деплоем у вас косяк. Проверьте какая версия запускается.